# Sanctuary.Js Type Error with Identity Functor

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js, fantasyland, sanctuary

I am playing around following Bartosz Milewski category theory lessons on youtube.  He describes Const and Identity functors as the "base" functors can be derived from (probably a liberal paraphrasing on my part).

My problem, having implemented ES6+ / fantasy-land (not important) version of the functor, appears once I start to integrate with the Sanctuary libary for map and pipe.

The implementation is pretty simple

```
const {map: flMap, extract } = require('fantasy-land');

const getInstance = (self, constructor) =>
    (self instanceof constructor) ?
        self :
        Object.create(constructor.prototype) ;

const Identity = function(x){
    const self = getInstance(this, Identity)

    self[flMap] = f => Identity(f(x))
    self[extract] = () => x

    return Object.freeze(self)
}
```

Here is some simple usage (as I was also working ion deriving lenses)

```
// USAGE
const {map, pipe, curry} = require("sanctuary")

const extractFrom = x => x[extract]()

const setter = (f, x) => (pipe([
    Identity,
    map(f),
    extractFrom
])(x))

const double = x => x + x

console.log(Identity(35)) //=> 35
console.log(map(double, Identity(35))) // ERROR Should be Identity(70)
console.log(setter(double, 35)) // ERROR Should be: 70
```

> ```
> TypeError: Type-variable constraint violation
>
> map :: Functor f => (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
>                      ^            ^
>                      1            2
>
> 1)  35 :: Number, FiniteNumber, NonZeroFiniteNumber, Integer,
>     NonNegativeInteger, ValidNumber
>
> 2)  () => x :: Function, (c -> d)
>     f => Identity(f(x)) :: Function, (c -> d)
>
> Since there is no type of which all the above values are members, the
> type-variable constraint has been violated.
> ```

However the Const functor works a bit better (no f invoked in map)

```
const Const = function(x) {
    const self = getInstance(this, Const)

    self[map] = _ =>  Const(x)
    self[extract] = () => x

    return Object.freeze(self)
}

const getter = (f, x) => (pipe([
    Const,
    map(f),
    extractFrom
])(x))

console.log(getter(double, 35)) //=> 35
```

Further everything is "logically sound" as proven by removing the type checking

```
const {create, env} = require('sanctuary'); 
const {map, pipe, curry} = create({checkTypes: false, env: env});
```

or replacing sanctuary with ramda.  SO it looks like some sort of type consistency problem with Identity map function.

Question is how do I get all these parts to play together in a type happy sort of way.

Comment: I notice that `extractFrom` doesn't seem to be defined.  Is it just `foo => foo.extract()`?

Comment: Sorry - perhaps I missed it.  but yeah essentially that (fl compliant).

Comment: Have you seen https://github.com/sanctuary-js/sanctuary-identity?

Comment: Have you tried `map(double)(Identity(35))` instead of `map(double, Identity(35))`?  Sanctuary is much more strict about things like this than Ramda.

Comment: @davidchambers I had not.  Thank you - the only thing I see there is that you have that type registered as a UnaryType and added to the environment. Is that the major deficiency OR is there something else that may be obviously wrong?

Comment: @ScottSauyet thank you for your suggestion.  Yes it is essentially through the setter method.  But i just tested explicitly (since  you made the suggestion) and no it doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to define a type constructor for your type (`IdentityType :: Type -> Type`), and include `IdentityType ($.Unknown)` in your Sanctuary environment as described in the [`S.create`](https://sanctuary.js.org/#create) documentation. Specifically, you'll need something like this:

```
//    IdentityType :: Type -> Type
const IdentityType = $.UnaryType
  ('my-package/Identity')
  ('http://example.com/my-package#Identity')
  (x => type (x) === Identity['@@type'])
  (identity => [Z.extract (identity)]);

const S = create ({
  checkTypes: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production',
  env: env.concat ([IdentityType ($.Unknown)]),
});
```

In the snippet above, `$` refers to [sanctuary-def](https://github.com/sanctuary-js/sanctuary-def), `Z` refers to [sanctuary-type-classes](https://github.com/sanctuary-js/sanctuary-type-classes), and `type` refers to [sanctuary-type-identifiers](https://github.com/sanctuary-js/sanctuary-type-identifiers).

Comment: For my education why isn't this an issue for the Const functor? And generally when do you need to add the type definitions to Types and functions and when not?

Comment: The environment is required when resolving type variables in polymorphic function signatures. Consider `S.concat :: Semigroup a => a -> a -> a`. Given `S.concat (x) (y)` Sanctuary must first determine all the types of which `x` is a member. It must then filter this set to include only the types of which `y` is also a member. If the resulting set is the empty set, type checking fails. So, `S.I (Identity (42))` will fail type checking if `Identity (42)` is not a member of any type in the environment.

Comment: So, because map is (a -> b) -> F a -> F b, where F a is the type Identity(35), and therefore Identity is represented by F, we need Sancutary to be able to determine that relationship (Identity is represented by F) so the can assure map returns the right type? And because Const doesn't have the transformation applied in map, we don't need to validate the return of Const.map?

Comment: That's right. I still recommend defining `ConstType :: Type -> Type` and including it in your environment so you could provide `Const (42)` as an argument to a polymorphic Sanctuary function.